# I think I disabled the Terminal?

Tags: command-line, python

Oh dear.. I was trying to install the latest version of Python and was following instructions online. One of the instructions said to change the /usr/bin/python symlink to point to a different version.

Now I'm no longer able to open up the terminal, and there's a red error message in the top right that says "A problem occurred when checking for updates".

Is there any way to fix this? Do I need to reinstall the entire operating system?

[Enter a Command image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz5nX.png)

Comment: If you know what you did, how about switching to a TTY with Alt+Ctrl+F2, logging in and reversing the command(s)?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what I typed. I think I changed the symlink but I'm not sure what it's supposed to be, or what I changed it to.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt install --reinstall python`? This should restore the symlink.

Comment: The Alt + Ctrl + F2 doesn't do anything, but Fn + Alt + F2 opens a white window that says "Enter a command". When I type the sudo command in there it doesn't do anything, the terminal is still disabled.

Comment: Try ctrl + Alt + F3  (F2 is now typically the GUI).  Login at the prompt, and try your command,

Comment: I tried Ctrl + Alt + F3, and Fn + Alt + F3 but nothing happens. I downloaded something called XTerm that seems to be like a terminal. I typed in the sudo command to reinstall python, it's at version 3.7.3. But the terminal itself is still not working. If Ubuntu runs on an old version of Python do I need to reinstall that as well?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1141325/edit) your post with add a picture of white window

Comment: Okay, I added an image.

Answer (score 1):

The default /usr/bin/python link is to python2.7 so remove the existing link (to some python 3 version) by typing in the xterm you start or in the little white window:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
```

Then create a new link (in the xterm or white window):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

That should restore the proper python and fix the problems you have.

---

Do you have a python link in /etc/alternatives ?  I don't, so if you do, may just remove it:

```
sudo rm /etc/alternatives/python
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions; I entered those commands but the terminal is still broken. I was looking through search my history to try & figure out what I entered and I think I typed something like this: "sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1" OR
"sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 2".

Comment: It says there’s no Python there, but there is Python3.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyways! I couldn't figure it out so I ended up reformatting the drive.